# PHP5.3 FastCGI doesn't use global config's values

Tags: linux, php, centos, fastcgi

There's a Centos6.3 system. Apache 2.2.15 + mod_fcgid + PHP 5.3.3

There's a problem with `date.timezone` value. It's mentioned in the global `/etc/php.ini` like this:

`date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"`

And doesn't mentioned in user's local php.ini. As a result, I'm getting lot's of warnings like:

`Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EEST/3.0/DST' instead in ...`

Including the `date.timezone` parameter into the user's php.ini solves the problem, but I don't think, that it's the best solution.

Maybe someone have faced this problem and can give an advice?

Thanks!

P.S. Creating `/etc/php.d/timezone.ini` with the timezone info aslo does nothing:(

Comment: What's the output of `php -i`, and how does it compare to `php -i -c /path/to/user.ini`. We're looking for **Configuration File (php.ini) Path**, **Loaded Configuration File**, and **Scan this dir for additional .ini files** settings.

Comment: From root:
`php -i | less`

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc;

Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini;

Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d;

Additional .ini files parsed =>;

`php -i -c /path/to/users/php.ini | less`

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc;

Loaded Configuration File => /var/www/php-bin/badho159/php.ini;

Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d;

Additional .ini files parsed =>

Comment: Sorry for the formatting:(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `date.timezone` record for each user's `ini` file. After some experiments, it appears that date timezone will default to global value, but still issue the **E_NOTICE** and/or **E_STRICT** or **E_WARNING**.

Testing global setting

```bsh
bash~> php -r 'print ini_get("date.timezone").PHP_EOL;'
Europe/Moscow

bash~> php -r 'print date_default_timezone_get().PHP_EOL;'
Europe/Moscow
```

Testing user.ini without `date.timezone` set

```bsh
bash~> php -c /path/to/user.ini -r 'print ini_get("date.timezone").PHP_EOL;'
""

bash~> php -c /path/to/user.ini -r 'print date_default_timezone_get().PHP_EOL;'
Warning: ... We selected 'Europe/Moscow' for 'EEST/4.0/DST' instead in Command line code on line 1

Europe/Moscow
```

The only other alternative would be to require each application to set the default timezone programmatically, but that's unrealistic & much more effort.

```php
if(!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sounds interesting. But I've tested it on my server and get the same result: `We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EEST/3.0/DST' instead in` and it shows `Europe/Helsinki`. I don't know, what is it's choice depends on, but I have `EEST` global timezone on my server. What is yours? Could you please repeat the test with another timezone in `/etc/php.ini`?